# VS Generated WSDL Namespace Issues

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces, wsdl

Good Afternoon,

We have been trying to consume a Carrier API, but have hit some issue with the WSDL Generation.  The Example XML message the company has provided has ns1-3 and appears that it is important for the address fields.  the XML generated from their WSDL seems to generate the same fields but has no name spaces like the original and fails with "Address details are invalid",  Is there some setting we are missing so that it generates the correct XML?

This is their Example XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <ns3:CreateLabel xmlns:ns3="http://courier.ck.dx.metafour.com/" xmlns:ns2="http://www.thedx.co.uk/eai/canonical/types/v2.0">
         <order>
            <ns2:customerID>14337622</ns2:customerID>
            <ns2:dates>
               <date format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" type="requestedCollectionDate">2018-12-12 17:59:21</date>
            </ns2:dates>
            <sourceSystemReference xmlns="http://www.thedx.co.uk/eai/canonical/types/v2.0">AMS207554</sourceSystemReference>
            <customerReference xmlns="http://www.thedx.co.uk/eai/canonical/types/v2.0">286956</customerReference>
            <orderAttributes xmlns="http://www.thedx.co.uk/eai/canonical/types/v2.0" xsi:nil="true" />
            <ns2:orderLines>
               <ns2:consignment>
                  <pieces>
                     <dimensions>
                        <value>1.0</value>
                        <type>cdlWeight</type>
                        <UOM>KG</UOM>
                     </dimensions>
                     <barcode xsi:nil="true" />
                     <trackingNumber xsi:nil="true" />
                  </pieces>
                  <qty>1</qty>
                  <legacyService>
                     <name>serviceLevel</name>
                     <partyId>0</partyId>
                     <partyType>HITS</partyType>
                  </legacyService>
                  <legacyService>
                     <name>serviceType</name>
                     <partyId>2</partyId>
                     <partyType>HITS</partyType>
                  </legacyService>
                  <deliverTo>
                     <ns2:address primary="true">
                        <organisationName>Argos</organisationName>
                        <addressLine1>Argos</addressLine1>
                        <addressLine2>Argos Ltd</addressLine2>
                        <addressLine3>11 Canning Street</addressLine3>
                        <city>BURNLEY</city>
                        <postalCode>BB12 0AD</postalCode>
                        <country>
                           <countryCode>GB</countryCode>
                           <description>GB</description>
                        </country>
                     </ns2:address>
                     <contact />
                  </deliverTo>
               </ns2:consignment>
            </ns2:orderLines>
            <labelType>ZPL</labelType>
         </order>
         <serviceHeader>
            <password>test</password>
            <userId>test</userId>
         </serviceHeader>
      </ns3:CreateLabel>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

This is our Generated XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <CreateLabel xmlns="http://courier.ck.dx.metafour.com/">
         <order xmlns="">
            <customerID xmlns="http://www.thedx.co.uk/eai/canonical/types/v2.0">14337622</customerID>
            <dates xmlns="http://www.thedx.co.uk/eai/canonical/types/v2.0">
               <date xmlns="" format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" type="requestedCollectionDate">2019-01-25 10:17:33</date>
            </dates>
            <sourceSystemReference xmlns="http://www.thedx.co.uk/eai/canonical/types/v2.0">AMS207554</sourceSystemReference>
            <customerReference xmlns="http://www.thedx.co.uk/eai/canonical/types/v2.0">286956</customerReference>
            <orderAttributes xmlns="http://www.thedx.co.uk/eai/canonical/types/v2.0" xsi:nil="true" />
            <orderLines xmlns="http://www.thedx.co.uk/eai/canonical/types/v2.0">
               <consignment>
                  <pieces xmlns="">
                     <dimensions>
                        <value>1.0</value>
                        <type>cdlWeight</type>
                        <UOM>KG</UOM>
                     </dimensions>
                     <barcode xsi:nil="true" />
                     <trackingNumber xsi:nil="true" />
                  </pieces>
                  <qty>1</qty>
                  <legacyService xmlns="">
                     <name>serviceLevel</name>
                     <partyId>0</partyId>
                     <partyType>HITS</partyType>
                  </legacyService>
                  <legacyService xmlns="">
                     <name>serviceType</name>
                     <partyId>2</partyId>
                     <partyType>HITS</partyType>
                  </legacyService>
                  <deliverTo xmlns="">
                     <address xmlns="http://www.thedx.co.uk/eai/canonical/types/v2.0">
                        <organisationName xmlns="">Argos</organisationName>
                        <addressLine1 xmlns="">Argos</addressLine1>
                        <addressLine2 xmlns="">Argos Ltd</addressLine2>
                        <addressLine3 xmlns="">11 Canning Street</addressLine3>
                        <city xmlns="">BURNLEY</city>
                        <postalCode xmlns="">BB12 0AD</postalCode>
                        <country xmlns="">
                           <countryCode>GB</countryCode>
                           <description>GB</description>
                        </country>
                     </address>
                     <contact xmlns="http://www.thedx.co.uk/eai/canonical/types/v2.0" />
                  </deliverTo>
               </consignment>
            </orderLines>
            <labelType>ZPL</labelType>
         </order>
         <serviceHeader xmlns="">
            <password>test</password>
            <userId>test</userId>
         </serviceHeader>
      </CreateLabel>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I see other elements that are the same situation but presumably not causing an error so are you sure it is a namespace problem? Do you need to mark the address as primary=true? Does DX have support for their api?

Comment: So their support pretty much shoved the example at me and said this works.   It is possible that primary=true needs to be there, but the generated references.cs has put primary as a value of address and not as an xml property (Not sure how to change that)  when setting primary to true in the code, it changes nothing on the XML

Comment: XML serialization requires classes. Does you classes include the namespace parameter?  (In the square brackets)

Comment: The class does include a namespace parameter  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.thedx.co.uk/eai/canonical/types/v2.0")]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved,

I could not figure out a way to change or add additional namespace to the generated references.cs file, and ended up sending the SOAP to their server manually with an XML string serialized using a httpWebRequest and XmlSerializer